# Can not log in the google account in eclipse

Tags: google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

i am trying to deploy my application to google app engine, and i asked to login my google account. However, after i typed in my account id and password in the internal browser of eclipse, it stuck in a blank page. Does anyone know how to fix it?

My version of eclipse is 64-bit kelper.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a temporary blip. You could try again, restart eclipse or wait a while. Additionally, I would also suggest to logout of your accounts, visit http://appengine.google.com and see if that works from your browser.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, and i also tried the other version of eclipse but it still not work for me.